# Save XML items locally with Phonegap

Tags: android, xml, cordova, favorite

I have been building an Android application using Phonegap, which parses and shows an XML file. This works fine and all, but I want to add an extra function, so people can mark/save items from the XML file as favorites.

How can I copy all content from within one XML-element (everything from `<item>` to `</item>`) to a local xml file? After that, I just have to parse the local xml file, and the user will be able to see al his favorited posts. That won't be a problem. What will be/is a problem though, is creating that XML and adding items. Not unimportant is a remove function as well.

Or is there a way easier and smarter way than saving something locally?

Maybe I completely missed a tutorial that explains this, then please point me towards it!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense for you to use the [FileWriter](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter) to save the XML file to the SD card or internal storage. Then if you save the url to the file you can load it using XHR which will allow you to easily parse the XML again. Here is a blog post where I [load a .sql file from a file url](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2011/12/on-fourth-day-of-phonegapping-creating.html) that you can adapt.